# How can I stop indexing in xcode 8?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, indexing, xcode8

I'm trying refactor a class name, but I can't change this because indexing is running, and the project is very big, and this not stop...

I'm trying use this command in console mac:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable 1
```

What is the correct way?

Thanks!